# Газопровод оказался не идеален. Слитное ли написание или раздельное?

Tags: частица-не

Газопровод оказался не идеален или неидеален.

Comment: Думаю, дело не в краткости-полности, а в сказуемости (раздельно).

Answer (score 4):

Выбираем вариант: **Газопровод оказался не идеален.**

Грамматика позволяет в данном случае использовать отрицание или утверждение, но слова "неидеальный", неидеален" вообще употребляются редко, так как не содержат нового смысла по сравнению с отрицательными выражениями "не идеальный, не идеален".

Comment: Один портал даетКраткие прилагательные, которые пишутся раздельно:

Не расположен, не готов, не должен,
не склонен, не обязан, не намерен и не рад.

Comment: а все остальные пишется слитно, как и полная форма

Comment: При выборе формы написания очень полезно заглядывать в Нацкорпус: как там люди пишут? http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E5+%E8%E4%E5%E0%EB%E5%ED  В нашем случае соотношение 20:1 в пользу формы "не идеален". После этого правило заставляет задуматься. В действительности там перечислены варианты слов, которые ВСЕГДА пишутся раздельно. В остальных случаях при наличии двух форм написания нам приходится выбирать подходящую.